# Directive implementation advice using attribute string binding

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am new to AngularJS and directives and am seeking some advice or guidance on a directive I have implemented. The directive in question will be used to display pdf's to the user. The directive exposes two attributes, documentPath and documentType that are defined using isolated scope as follows:

```
    var directiveDefinition = {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/directives/document.html', 
        scope: {
            documentPath: '@documentPath', 
            documentType: '@documentType' 
        },
        restrict: 'E',                                  
        templateNamespace: 'html',
        link: linkFunc
    };
```

In the view that uses the directive, I bind the properties using a model property for the view controller and a string.

```
<my-document document-path="{{ application.documentpath }}" document-type="Application"></my-document>
```

When I initially ran this, I found that the directive would sometimes run before the data had been returned by the model. So an empty document would be displayed. Other times, the model would load before the directive ran, so the document path would be present when the link function ran, allowing the document to be displayed.

I determined that one way to resolve this was to use a $watch listener on the documentPath attribute of the directive. This seems to resolve the issue.

Being new to AngularJS and also directive implementation my question is...was this the best solution? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `$watch` solution should work fine but depending on the complexity of your app and the number of total watchers this could lead to a slow `$digest` cycle.

Another option would be to send the parameters as a reference using the "." **dot notation** so you it will get updated when the data gets loaded from model (from the API most of the time since this is the slow part) instead of sending a string primitive.

Your directive scope declaration would become:

```
scope: {
        documentPath: '=', 
        documentType: '=' 
    },
```

and you will use it from the parent view like this:

```
<my-document document-path="application.documentpath" document-type="application.documenttype"></my-document>
```

If the *documentType* is always the same you may leave it as a string scope parameter.

Comment: Thank you bosch for the resopnse. A followup question will passing the parameter by reference require the $watch or will the directive wait to run until the data is available?